# Libgit2 running on Android unable to perform clone operation - returns "failed to set permissions" error

Tags: android, java-native-interface, chmod, libgit2

I have just built Libgit2 (v0.20.0) for Android (target SDK version 18, debugging on a rooted device running Cyanogenmod 10.1.2, Android 4.2.2) and a simple function like getting the version number of Libgit2 works fine through the JNI. But when I use the git_clone function it stops right after the objects/info folder is created and returns this error:

```
Error -1 cloning repository - Failed to set permissions on '/storage/sdcard0/it/ptt/.git/objects/info': Operation not permitted
```

I have given the application the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but I guess it still can't chmod unless owner of the file. When I use adb shell to check out the permission mode of the info folder I get:

```
d---rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2014-05-15 09:31 info
```

And by using `pwd.h` functions I get the username that the c code (that is calling git_clone) is under to be `u0_a92`. How am I suppose to get pass this I suppose very Android related issue? Is there a simple way to stop Libgit2 from calling `p_chmod` or can I give it permissions to do so?

Comment: Does it *crash* or do you mean it returns an error? If it crashes, that's a very bad bug in libgit2, if it returns an error, it's a quirk of android.

Comment: Oh sorry I shouldn't have said it crashed - it doesn't actually crash, just stops cloning the repository right after the objects/info folder is created and returns the error. Edited the title now

Comment: There's some similar reports for sqlite failing to set. It looks like a thing that android just doesn't let you do. As a dirty workaround, you could define `p_chmod()` to be a no-op or to ignore errors when building for android. It could be an android thing, or it could be a FAT thing, or...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining `p_chmod` as a method always returning true to get passed the error. In the bash script I use to build libgit2 I inserted the following lines that leaves the source files in an unmodified condition after building for android:

```
LIBGIT2_POSIX_PATH="$LIBGIT2_SOURCE_PATH/src/posix.h"
LIBGIT2_POSIX_BACKUP_PATH="$LIBGIT2_SOURCE_PATH/src/posix_original.h"
printf "#include \"always_success.h\"\nint always_success() { return 0; }" > "$LIBGIT2_SOURCE_PATH/src/always_success.c"
printf "int always_success();" > "$LIBGIT2_SOURCE_PATH/src/always_success.h"
cp $LIBGIT2_POSIX_PATH "$LIBGIT2_POSIX_BACKUP_PATH"
sed -i "s/^#define\sp_chmod(p, m).*$/#include \"always_success.h\"\n#define p_chmod(p, m) always_success()\nextern int always_success();\n/" $LIBGIT2_POSIX_PATH

# run the build process with cmake ...

# restore chmod manipulated source header
mv $LIBGIT2_POSIX_BACKUP_PATH $LIBGIT2_POSIX_PATH
```

There is probably a cleaner way to solve this but at least now I dont get that error anymore. Thanks to Carlos for his help!

**UPDATE**
Running `adb shell mount | grep sdcard` I could see that the sdcard which I am trying to clone the repository into uses the vfat file system which according to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-chown-chgrp-chmod-on-a-vfat-partition-354125/) forum thread doesn't support unix-style permissions.